# How is the host WAN connecting WAN traffic to the host bridge WAN?

Tags: networking, 20.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Can someone help me understand how the WAN enp3s0 connects in Ubuntu on my virtual setup?

I just set up my desktop with a VM router. Just trying to map the topology. I can see and map the LAN traffic, but I don't understand how the WAN traffic connects from Wired connection1 to VM router WAN?

I suspect the last connection I'm missing on my topology map may be Wired connection1 to virbr0, but I can't confirm with any evidence?

The VM router is bridged from LAN vtnet0 to host bridge local-br1.1 and from WAN vtnet1 to host bridge virbr0.

I think the host needs a connection from host bridge WAN virbr0 to either host nic0 or host wired connection1?

I can match up bridge masters and slaves from ip -c a results and ip route, but see no info on the WAN?

Details:
[Topology map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnScZ.png) https://i.imgur.com/SN3AB9H.png

```
Host:$ ip -c a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master local-br1.1 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 46:9e:01:27:db:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 1c:61:b4:6d:38:4f
3: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:6e:1f:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 100.76.25.213/10 brd 100.127.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 278sec preferred_lft 278sec
    inet6 2406:2d40:4100:8fb2:7b54:ac94:277b:140f/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 233sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 2406:2d40:4100:8fb2:f995:e028:b158:4865/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 233sec preferred_lft 83sec
    inet6 fe80::8cc1:c5d0:5e3e:28b1/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:94:0d:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: local-br1.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2e:f6:bf:42:0c:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.120/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute local-br1.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master local-br1.1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:3d:53:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe3d:5341/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master virbr0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:a3:f6:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fea3:f6c4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: vnet3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master local-br1.1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:8d:31:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe8d:3106/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: vnet4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master local-br1.1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:f7:f9:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fef7:f9e5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: vnet5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master local-br1.1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:b6:35:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:feb6:3537/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Host:$ arp -n
Address HWtype HWaddress Flags Mask Iface
192.168.1.160 ether 3c:2a:f4:60:b5:7b C local-br1.1
192.168.1.1 ether 52:54:00:3d:53:41 C local-br1.1
192.168.122.149 ether 52:54:00:a3:f6:c4 C virbr0
192.168.1.102 ether 52:54:00:8d:31:06 C local-br1.1
192.168.1.100 ether 1c:ca:e3:77:c5:53 C local-br1.1
100.64.0.1 ether 00:00:5e:00:01:01 C enp3s0

Host:$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
default _gateway 0.0.0.0 UG 102 0 0 enp3s0
244.255.120.34. 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 102 0 0 enp3s0
100.64.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.192.0.0 U 102 0 0 enp3s0
link-local 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 U 1000 0 0 virbr0
192.168.1.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 425 0 0 local-br1.1
192.168.100.1 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 102 0 0 enp3s0
192.168.122.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 virbr0

Host:$ ip route
default via 100.64.0.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 102
34.120.255.244 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp scope link metric 102
100.64.0.0/10 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 100.76.25.213 metric 102
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev local-br1.1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.120 metric 425
192.168.100.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp scope link metric 102
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1
```